# 2sxc View Does Not Have App Context When Rendered From Another App's View

Tags: 2sxc, dnn9

I have 2 different 2sxc apps on my site - I'll refer to them as App1 and App2. A content type in App1 uses a "String dropdown-query" field to get the GUID of an entity from App2.

Within an App1 view, I am using that GUID in a query (using App.Query) to retrieve the entity data from App2. This all works successfully; I have no trouble displaying this data.

```
// App1 View
...
var getPlaylist = App.Query["Get Playlist by GUID"];
getPlaylist.Params("PlaylistId", "16705");
var playlist = AsList(getPlaylist["Default"]).First(); // Returns entity data from App2

<p>@playlist.EntityTitle</p> // App2 data displays correctly
```

Additionally, I would like to render a view from App2 within App1, passing in the entity data from App.Query. This is almost working correctly.

```
@RenderPage("/portals/0/2sxc/Artifact-Library/_ResourcesDownload.cshtml", new { Content = playlist })
```

When the view is rendered, the entity data all displays correctly. However, additional context from App2 seems to be lost; e.g. the toolbar buttons raise an error when clicked (included below), and any references to App2's settings or resources returns empty.

```
Had an error talking to the server (status 400),
Message: Bad Request
Detail: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Is there a way I can preserve App2's context within App1's view? Or is there at least a way to make the toolbar work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the `IRenderService` - ideally on the `Kit.Render` - probably something like:

```cs
@Kit.Render.Module(pageId, moduleId)
```

Comment: That would be a suitable solution if I was always displaying the same content from App2. The problem is I’m dealing with large amounts of content entities in App1, which each require a different entity from App2. This means that in order for each entity from App1 to display correctly, I would have to first configure the corresponding entity from App2 on another page, which is not ideal for large amounts of data. Is there a way to render a view from App2 with context without having to add it to another page first?

Comment: I'm confused about the Context - what is it of the context you need? eg. the user is the same etc. - so what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, the solution is another version of .Render.Module() that additionally passes in Page Parameters. Then you could `var myHtml Kit.Render.Module(pageId, moduleId, pageParams: new { "app2Guid", theGuid })` - this doesn't exist currently, but I really like the idea!! Using Render like this to use another page+module like a "factory" for generating output sounds very cool and useful (to me)! Though I suspect it would be either a resource or performance hog.

Comment: The above assumes you have modified the module/app2 to use page params to make its output.

Comment: I have a feeling I really don't understand the question. Adding some more real-life explanations would help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that with the term **Context** you want to pass in some parameters. If that is your wish, you're in luck, because we added a `data` parameter in 15.07

https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Services.IRenderService.html#ToSic_Sxc_Services_IRenderService_Module_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_String_System_Object_

```cs
@Kit.Render.Module(pageId, moduleId, data: new {isGreen = true })
```

Note that these parameters are like control parameters, so you would end up writing something like this in the child-razor:

```cs
@inherits Custom.Hybrid.Razor14
@{
  var isGreen = DynamicModel.IsGreen as bool;
}
```

or if you're already typed

```cs
@inherits Custom.Hybrid.Razor14
@{
  var isGreen = MyModel.Bool("IsGreen", fallback: false);
}
```

Note that this will be available in the razor control, but will not affect anything that listens to the url parameters, such as an underlying query.